# Prove there are two points an integral number of inches apart of the same colour

Tags: combinatorics, coloring

A line is coloured in $11$ colours. Prove that there are two points of the same colour that are an integral number of inches apart.

I don't know how to do this, but I know how to do a similar problem of proving there are no two points an integral number of inches apart if a plane is coloured in two colours. Just drop an equilateral triangle !

I have a feeling that there is nothing special about $11$ here or the requirement of integral distances. It needs some construction, which will prove that there are always $d$ apart. Although, such a construction eludes me at the moment.

Comment: Do you mean "two points of the same color"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea behind your equilateral triangle argument for the plane works for this problem. Apply the pigeonhole principle to the coloring of the set of points $\{1,2, \ldots, 12\}$.

The same argument proves something much stronger. For any $n$ and any number of colors you can be sure that you can find $n$ points all the same color with mutually integral distances.

(I assume, as @coffeemath comments, that you want two points the same color an integral distance apart. Your argument in the plane finds two points one unit apart.)

Comment: Oh wow. I didn't think it would be that easy. Feel silly now.

Comment: No need to feel silly. It's a congenital disease of mathematicians to think that a problem is easy and should have been obvious - once it's done.